# Atrribute Error in Django web application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been trying this for some days now with no solution.I am getting this weird error after which I have made several trials all of which hasn't solved my issue, I would be glad to receive a solution.

```
ERROR LOGS

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\student_management_app\StaffViews.py", line 364, in get_queryset
    queryset = self.request.user.quizzes \
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /staff_quiz_home/
Exception Value: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'quizzes'
```

```
MODELS.PY

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data = ((1, "HOD"), (2, "Staff"), (3, "Student"))
    user_type = models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Staffs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quizzes')

class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')

class Staffs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()

class Subjects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    staff_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
VIEWS.PY

class QuizListView(ListView):
    model = Quiz
    ordering = ('name', )
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    template_name = "staff_template/quiz_home_page.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.request.user.quizzes \
            .select_related('subject') \
            .annotate(questions_count=Count('questions', distinct=True)) \
            .annotate(taken_count=Count('taken_quizzes', distinct=True))
        return queryset
```

Thanks in advance, if you need anymore info please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Quiz object is related to Staffs and not CustomUser so you should access it through

```
 self.request.user.staffs.quizess
```

Other than that it is clear that you cannot do Query on a set so you should do something in a line of

```
 Quiz.object.filter(owner__admin=request.user).
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sir, it worked just perfectly. i am really happy